# Is it possible for a device to remember settings after turning the pc off?

Tags: power-management

I once had a problem with a sound card in my computer. After installing drivers under windows and setting the card, I had to mute it. Then I turned my pc off and loaded a linux OS from another disk. The system started, and everything was just fine, but there was no sound at all. I tried everything, but there was no way to turn it on. It looked as if it was still muted, but the software was telling something different. The only thing I could do was to unplug my computer and wait 1-2 mins. When I booted the linux system again, the sound appeared. This issue occurred to me two or three times, and each time it was solved by disconnecting the pc from the source of power.

The other thing is about enabling/disabling wi-fi in laptops. I had the problem, and this also occurred to one person I know. Usually you can turn on/off the wi-fi card in your laptop by pressing f12 button. But in some cases the device is off and you can't turn it on. I disabled my wi-fi card via gnome control center (or whatever it's called) when I was using debian live. After I finished, I booted my debian box, which is just standalone openbox. The `rfkill` tool said that the wi-fi device is turned off for some reason, and I was unable to enable it. So I booted the live system again and enabled wi-fi from the control center. Then the wi-fi card was also seen in my normal system as enabled. The person I mentioned before removed just the battery of his laptop. After some time he put the battery in and booted the system. In that case the wi-fi card was also unblocked.

I can turn off/on (or unmute/mute) devices when I start the same system, but it looks like something happens when another (different) system is booted, especially when a device was disabled in the previous one.

Does anyone know how it's possible that a device can remember software settings even after turning the whole computer off? Is there a way to turn that device on under the other system without cutting the power off?

Comment: I am not sure if this helps you. But updating the driver might be one possible suggestion. http://askubuntu.com/a/112733

Comment: I'm afraid this is off topic since there is nothing *nix specific here. I will be migrating it to [su] in a second.

Comment: I'm not sure because I've never had this issue under windows. I'm not using it anymore, so I really don't know. But this occurs only when I switched from windows OS to linux OS, and I think that's related to linux systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of electronic components are able to remember their own state and it is entirely possible that Windows, having the proper drivers supplied by the manufacturer, is turning the output stage of your sound card off in a way that is not expected by the drivers in Linux/Unix.

When you simply reboot (or even shutdown) power is still applied to a number of components and if any of those components are not fully reset on boot (as it is reasonable to expect the OS drivers to do setup when it starts up) then they will be effectively "latched" into their current state when the computer reboots. Your alternative system is required, but is failing, to do that setup itself.

Your Debian install is probably using highly generic drivers that can just about poke audio at the soundcard, but probably does not understand that there is a dedicated mute/unmute signal that the Windows drivers are using.  Updating your drivers *might* fix this.

Fully removing the power will remove the "latch" in these electronic components and in effect reset them to a fully default state which your Debian install can deal with.

Comment: That's strange because if a driver operates on a device, it should be able to do some things, for instance, let's say that the card was muted -- the driver should unmute it no matter what. Maybe it can do that in a different way, but the state of the device should be the same, so if it's muted, it's muted, am I right?

Comment: The driver might be able to do some things, but drivers in debian are almost certainly not written by the manufacturers of the actual hardware so may not support the same features that the Windows drivers support. Just because a driver supports the major features of the hardware does not mean it supports *all* the hardware features, especially when those drivers are written by a third party who are not privy to the details of the various revisions that the hardware undergoes.  One driver sending the correct mute signal does not mean that the other driver is sending the correct unmute signal.